# 2d to 3d video conversion

Tags: video, android

I'm looking for a method to convert a normal movie format like m4v or mkv and creating a file with side by side images that would be viewable in Vic for Android in a Google cardboard.

I have an old Android phone and the tilt and gyro sensors don't work with 3d video players.  You can't control anything.

What I would like to do is create the side by side video image from a normal mkv or m4v.  Then I would start the video and place it in the Google cardboard.  I don't care about the control aspect.

I didn't  find anything in other questions.   Googling gives a few windows centric solutions, but I don't have the darkside in my house.

Comment: Something like this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Stereoscopic ?

Comment: @andrew.46  The starting image is what I want to create.  2 side by side images from a single normal 2d movie.  I don't want to try to generate anaglyph images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Converting from 2D to 3D is impossible...

**Why?** Because of the [entropy of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe) of course!  **:-)**
<sub>(**Meaning:** You cannot add what's not there; 3D movies are filmed with 2 cameras, one of each eye; 2D movies are filmed with 1 camera)¹</sub>

#### Converting from 2D to Side-by-Syde (SBS) 2D is possible however:

```
ffmpeg -i 2D.mp4 -filter_complex \
       "[0]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,scale=-1:$720,\
        crop=$720:$720,split[left][right]; \
        [left][right]hstack[sbs]" -map "[sbs]" -map 0:a? SBS.mp4
```

which will give you a movie that you can still watch using cardboard, but it'll be 2D, not 3D.

in the above command, you can change the following options:

- `720` to the resolution you want (SD=540, HD=720,FHD=1080, but any value can be taken)
- `2D.mp4` is the input file
- `SBS.mp4` is the output file

¹<sub>Yes, it's more complex than that, but let's keep it simple...  **;-)**</sub>

Comment: The very thing!  I shall attempt this when I get home, and return with many questions when my ineptitude with command line is revealed ;-)  Thanks, I really will give it a shot tonight and accept this answer if it works.  I don't care about true 3d, I just want to use my cheap google cardboard to watch movies without light pollution

Comment: I agree in general, yet in theory you can infer quite some depth information from moving images. Try enforcing a delay of a couple of frames for one eye, it kind of works for some scenes. Also, with very advanced algorithms you could certainly add some 3D information that is not completely off. As far as I know this is in fact happening in quite some blockbuster productions.

Comment: Yes, and it works well for old-fashioned cartoons, but not so much for RL movies and that's not what OP was looking for: he just wants to watch Google Cardboard movies on his android phone without light spilling in from the outside... @SebastianStark

Comment: @PaulTIKI And? did it work?

Comment: Thanks a ton.  Took a few tries (I'm not a master of the command line).  Next to try it on an actual movie

Comment: I'm happy for you!  Favour returned and question upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method I use with FFmpeg the results are a bit primitive, but quite simple. Try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.04 -i foo.mp4 -i foo.mp4 -filter_complex hstack out-sbs.mp4
```

The `-ss` is a time advance of about 1/25 of a second or about one frame. `foo` is  what ever your video is, mp4 seems to be the best but works with any. The two input files are about 1 frame out of sync, but when you stack them side by side it tricks your brain into thinking the difference is parallax.

Its a crude method and not consistent, but sometimes surprisingly good. Great when viewed through a VR headset.